# Can we Synchronize the Gmail mails using Mail.dll

Tags: vb.net

I am using Mail.dll Commercial component. I can read the unseen or unread messages in my windows application. IF i open the mail using the gmail.com then I cannot get the mail in windows application. Is there any way to synchronize the gmail mails

Comment: You're going to have to give us more information. What specifically is "Mail.dll" (maker, version, etc)? How does the component access Gmail (HTTP/IMAP/POP)? Do you have a code example that you can post?

Comment: Mail.dll is [http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can get all emails, not only
   those with unseen flag: just use
   Imap.GetAll() method.
2. You can mark message as unseeen
   using Gmail online interface: just
   mark the mail, click "more actions",
   and click "mark as unread"
3. You can save last processed uid in your windows application:

Here's the code:

```
long lastProcessedUID = GetLastProcessedUID(); // returns -1 on first run
using (Imap client = new Imap())
{
   List<long> allUids = client.GetAll();
   List<long> toBeProcessed = allUids.FindAll(x => x > lastProcessedUID);

   foreach (long uid in toBeProcessed)
   {
       // process message here

       SaveLastProcessed(uid);
   }
   client.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. While synchronize the mailbox Using Unique Identifier Do we have performance issue in client.GetAll() [Incase of mailbox with 50,000 thousands or more emails]. Second thing can we use the unique indefier for MailBox Synchronization for more than on MailBoxes